# Holomorphic function and its injectivity

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am reading one book which states the following fact:

Suppose $f$ is an injective holomorphic function on $\{|z|>1\}$ and 
$$f(z)=z+b_0+b_1z^{-1}+b_2z^{-2}+\cdots$$
then 
$$\sum_{i=0}^nn|b_n|^2\leq 1$$
Is this a standard fact from complex analysis? How do we see it? Thank you very much.

Comment: [*Area theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) is what you may want to look at. Page 14 of [*this lecture note*](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/LectureNotes/univalent.pdf) may also be helpful.

Comment: That is so cool. Thank you for pointing that out. @SangchulLee